# Any specifications/docs around optimization of Google Apps Script, to avoid timeouts and "hangs"

Tags: google-apps-script

From my experience so far, it seems that if you write a script that makes lots of expensive calls close together, the functionality just "hangs", or you get inconsistent responses, and have to refresh the browser because sheets stop updating etc.

Are there any docs or specs that clarify this, as releasing an app fr real-world use is not possible if users can expect it to work most of the time, and produce random results every now and then...

Answer (score 0):

There's specifications/docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_common_tasks) and [here](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/optimizing-spreadsheet-operations.html).